# how to display only the minimum and the maximum values in a legend while using image.plot function

Tags: r

I am using image.plot function to display a color bar with a image. For the color bar, I wish to display the legend at its boundary positions Only. However, currently I am getting tics at various places in the middle. Moreover, the corresponding values are not getting displayed. Please see the code segment below:

```
  color_plate=c('royalblue4','springgreen4','yellow2','darkred')
    layout(matrix(c(1,1), 1, 1))
    par(mar=c(0,1,1,0))
#here image is plotted
    image(image_variable, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="",col=color_plate)

   image.plot(zlim=c(min(ya),max(ya)),legend.only=TRUE,col=color_plate,
    horizontal=TRUE,legend.mar=0.4,legend.shrink=0.4,legend.width=0.4,
    axis.args = list(cex.axis = 1.5))

#here color bar is added but I am not able to generate legend values at both ends.    
#Furthermore, I wish to eliminate the tics and only need the values to be displayed.                          
# I also tried two variations within the image.plot function but no result:
#axis.args = list(cex.axis = 1.5,at=c(floor(min(ya)),ceiling(max(ya))))
#and  
#axis.args = list(cex.axis = 1.5, at=c(0.01,0.05),labels=c(0.01,0.05))
```

Please suggest suitable modification in the segment.

Thanks in advance.
Munish

Comment: I can't run your code - could you please modify it to be a reproducible example? For example, `image_variable=array(runif(100),dim=c(10,10))`, what is `ya` ? And a `library(fields)` so that we can get `image.plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't run your example, I think I get what you mean, and I think you can tweak this to your `layout(..)`. Looking at `?image.plot`, there is an example for what you want - you use the `breaks` argument and the `lab.breaks` argument to `image.plot`:

```
# generate an image_variable for demonstration
image_variable <- array(runif(100),dim=c(10,10))
color_plate=c('royalblue4','springgreen4','yellow2','darkred')

library(fields) # for image.plot
# This puts the colour scale marks within the colour bar, not on the boundaries:
# image.plot(image_variable,col=color_plate,zlim=c(0,1),...)

zlim <- c(0,1)
# define colour breaks (they were default spaced evenly):
brks = seq(0,1,length.out=length(color_plate)+1)

# plot:
image.plot(image_variable, zlim=zlim, axes=F,
           col=color_plate, breaks=brks, lab.breaks=brks)
```

[image]

Hope that's what you wanted.

If you **only** want the 0 and 1, it's even easier:

```
image.plot(image_variable, col=color_plate, zlim=zlim, axes=F,
       axis.args=list(at=zlim, labels=zlim))
```

[image]

Comment: any idea how we can remove '-' that appears with 1 and 0 values in the color-bar? otherwise it works well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but read the documentation `?image.plot` and in particular, the `axis.args` parameter. Then read `?axis` and I'm sure you'll find the parameter you need (probably `tick=FALSE`).